# Nested Serializer Creation

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am using django rest framework. I am trying to use create() method for serializer. In DishSerializer when i am trying to pass Dish reference to the Ingredient instance It shows **Unaccepted keyword argument**

Ingredient Model class is:

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    dish_id  = models.ForeignKey(Dish, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null = True, related_name='ingredientInfo')
  .
  .
  .
```

Here is My Dish Serializer:

```
class DishSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):


        ingredientInfo      =       IngredientSerializer(many = True)

        class Meta:
            model  = Menu
            fields = ['id', 'name','type','status','ingredientInfo']

        def create(self , validated_data):
            ingredientInfo_data  =       validated_data.pop('ingredientInfo')
            dish                 =       Dish.objects.create(**validated_data)
            for info in ingredientInfo_data:
                Ingredient.objects.create(**info, dish = dish)
            return dish
```

It shows me **Ingredient() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dish'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `dish_id` as in your model:

```
Ingredient.objects.create(**info, dish_id = dish)
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I noticed:

```py
class ingredient(models.Model):
```

Are you sure that you shouldn't capitalize the class? Sorry that I can't comment since I don't have enough reputations.